# The minimal polynomial and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering about mininmal polynomials. Please can you tell me if my thoughts are correct:

For a linear operator $T:V\to V$ if there is an eigen basis of $V$ it can be said that the minimal polynomial $m_T$ of $T$ has $dim(V)$ distinct many roots.

In general it is not true because for example if $T=I$ then the minimal polynomial is $X-I$ has only one root ($=1$). But when there is an eigen basis the $T$ is of diagonal form $D$ and because $m_T(D) =0$ all diagonal entries are roots of $m_T$. If $n$ are the same and equal to $\lambda$ then $m_T = (x-\lambda )^n p(x)$. Then also $q(x) = (x-\lambda)p(x)$ is a polynomial with $q(D) = 0$. Which contradicts that $m_T$ is minimal.

Is it correct?

Comment: No, if some eigenvalue $\lambda$ has multiplicity $n\gt 1$ it does not follow that $(x-\lambda)^n$ is a factor of the minimal polynomial. $(x-\lambda)^n$ is a factor of $m_T(x)$ if and only if there is a vactor $v\in V$ such that $(T-\lambda\text{id})^n(v)\neq 0.$ Note in this context that the minimal polynomial is not (in general) the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. You have found that the statement fails for the identity, but you hope that is it will nevertheless work is there is an eigenbasis so that $T$ would be of diagonal form. Do you think that this special case somehow _does not_ apply to $T=I$? For that case there are $n$ diagonal entries equal to $1$, but $(x-1)^n$ does not divide the minimal polynomial $x-1$ (not $X-I$ by the way).